# How do I auto join this network without entering the username and password every time

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking

Or at least get the apple keychain to input the username and password for me. (This is a network I connect to every day and every time I do, this window pops up and makes me re-input username and password)

Im running OS Mojave - this is the pop up window for the network

[image: The pop up window for the network]

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in way. That network is set up as a "captive portal" that doesn't require any of the standard forms of 802.11 authentication that could be handled automatically. Instead, it hijacks and redirects all your web browser traffic to their "captive portal" web server until you authenticate with their web page.

macOS (and iOS) have the ability to detect that this is happening and pop-up a special window with an embedded web browser view. I think that's what you're seeing here, is what Apple calls the "Captive Networking" window. This is to save you from having to open a web browser and try to load an insecure website (plain HTTP, not HTTPS, because HTTPS isn't easily hijacked). HOWEVER, there are so many different ways that web pages can code the HTML for the username and password fields that web browsers can't always tell that username and password fields are being displayed, so there's no reliable way to code that embedded browser view to autofill those fields and autosubmit the form. It's also not a good idea to autosubmit a form that might also include agreeing to some kind of "terms of use" legal text.

If you have some web developer skills you might want to look at what kind of HTTP POST or other HTTP transaction happens when you submit that form, and maybe you can come up with a `curl` invocation that could do the equivalent thing, and maybe wrap that in a script that you can easily invoke.